# SubTitle and SubSubTitle do not group by default

Tags: front-end, cells

For some reason, the `SubTitle` and `SubSubTitle` cell formats do not group automatically on my machine any more, and I cannot figure out how to fix that.  To be explicit, here is a picture of the problem:

[image]

If you notice, only the topmost layer in the hierarchy will automatically group with those below it, until you reach the `Section` level (level-4 on the default stylesheet).  This makes using the notebook interface difficult for deeply nested topics, as there are only an effective 4 levels of grouping available to me.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the course of researching this question, I discovered an answer.

Looking at the *Option Inspector* -> *Cell Options* -> *General Properties* for each of the cells shown above, reveals the option: `CellGroupingRules`. Unfortunately, there is little in terms of [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellGroupingRules.html) for this option.

Upon inspection, `CellGroupingRules` has the value of `{"TitleGrouping", 0}`, `{"TitleGrouping", 10}`, and `{"TitleGrouping", 20}` for the three title cells, respectively, in order of appearance. The `Section` cells, down to the `SubSubSection` have `CellGroupingRules = {"SectionGrouping", x}` where `x` goes from 30 to 50 as you descend the hierarchy. So, obviously, the number indicates the level in the hierarchy. A `Text` cell (7th in the hierarchy) has `CellGroupingRules = "NormalGrouping"`.

Changing `CellGroupingRules` on `SubSubTitle` to `{"SectionGrouping", 20}` appears to do the trick. For whatever reason, `"TitleGrouping"` implies that sub-titles are not to be included in the grouping.

Comment: I think that TitleGrouping groups with the cell below if the cell is sandwiched with cells with lower hierarchy number. Section grouping just looks at the cell below... Could it be?

Comment: @Rojo I'm not sure what you're saying. Specifically, in reference to the TitleGrouping.

Comment: I mean, the different kinds of grouping specify the grouping rules. For example, I'm guessing OutputGrouping means that it should group with the cell above if it's InputGrouping, and InputGrouping the other way around. SectionGrouping seems to be similar to GroupTogetherNestedGrouping, the most natural way to group: group with the cell below if it has a higher number. Just like GroupTogetherNestedGrouping. I was guessing that TitleGrouping meant "make a new cell group with the cells below if the cells above and below have a higher number". All wild guess

Comment: @Rojo I thought that's what you meant. So, your speculating that because `Title` has a lower number than `SubTitle`, `SubTitle` won't be grouped because of `"TitleGrouping"`, correct?

Comment: I'm speculating that TitleGrouping doesn't group if you go adding cells from lowest to hightest: Title -> SubTitle -> SubsubTitle... It only groups when you jump up again. Title -> Subtitle -> SubsubTitle -HERE-> SubTitle -> SubsubTitle... Because this last SubTitle is between two cells with higher numbers (SubsubTitle)

Comment: @Rojo probably correct. Although, it is frustrating. Now to figure out how to modify my default stylesheet ...

Comment: I'm in the chat for now if I can be of help