# Making cells group

Tags: front-end, cells

After reading rcollyer's [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/subtitle-and-subsubtitle-do-not-group-by-default) I'm still not able to understand how grouping rules work.
Here is a problem I'm facing. What I want is to create a new title, section and subsection styles. I want the title to group everything below till the next title. The section should group everything below till the next section. To see what I mean, open up a new notebook. Go to `Format > Edit Stylesheet...`.

On this stylesheet make a new cell. Then select this cell and go to `Cell > Show Expression`.

Here enter the following:

```
Cell[StyleData["MyTitle"],
 CellGroupingRules->{"MyTitleGrouping", 0},
 CounterIncrements->"MyTitle",
 CounterAssignments->{{"MySection", 0}, {"MySubsection", 0}},
 FontSize->26,
]
```

Once this has been entered now go to `Cell > Show Expression` to revert back. Let us create two more cells in the same fashion, one for the section and subsection.

```
Cell[StyleData["MySection"],
 CellGroupingRules->{"MyTitleGrouping", 10},
 CounterIncrements->"MySection",
 CounterAssignments->{{"MySubsection", 0}},
 CellFrameLabels->{{
    Cell[
     TextData[
      CounterBox["MySection"], " -"], CellBaseline -> Baseline], Inherited}, {
   Inherited, Inherited}},
 FontSize->20,
]
```

Finally, the subsection:

```
Cell[StyleData["MySubsection"],
 CellGroupingRules->{"MyTitleGrouping", 20},
 CellFrameLabels->{{
    Cell[
     TextData[
      CounterBox["MySection"], ".", 
      CounterBox["MySubsection"], " -"], CellBaseline -> Baseline], 
    Inherited}, {Inherited, Inherited}},
 CounterIncrements->"MySubsection",
 FontSize->16,
]
```

After creating those new styles, now we can use them, here is a screenshot of what I obtained if I use the "MyTitle", "MySection" and "MySubsection" styles.

[image]

Don't mind the text I entered there. The main point here is that there is no grouping.

How can I make it behave as the regular "Title", "Section" and "Subsection" styles?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are inventing your own grouping types. If you open the Options Inspector and go to *Cell Options* -> *General Properties* -> *CellGroupingRules* the drop-down shows several options available: `"NormalGrouping"`, `"TitleGrouping"`, `"SectionGrouping"`, `"InputGrouping"`, `"OutputGrouping"`, `"GraphicsGrouping"`, `"GroupTogetherGrouping"`, and `"GroupTogetherNestedGrouping"`.

You have used `"MyTitleGrouping"` which is not part of the list. Per my previous [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3006/52), what you are looking for is `"TitleGrouping"` for `"MyTitle"` and `"SectionGrouping"` for `"MySection"` and `"MySubSection"`. Implementing these changes, your code becomes:

```
Cell[StyleData["MyTitle"],
 CellGroupingRules->{"TitleGrouping", 0},
 CounterIncrements->"MyTitle",
 CounterAssignments->{{"MySection", 0}, {"MySubsection", 0}},
 FontSize->26
]

Cell[StyleData["MySection"],
 CellGroupingRules->{"SectionGrouping", 10},
 CounterIncrements->"MySection",
 CounterAssignments->{{"MySubsection", 0}},
 CellFrameLabels->{{
    Cell[
     TextData[
      {CounterBox["MySection"], " -"}], CellBaseline -> Baseline], Inherited}, {
   Inherited, Inherited}},
 FontSize->20
]

Cell[StyleData["MySubsection"],
 CellGroupingRules->{"SectionGrouping", 20},
 CellFrameLabels->{{
    Cell[
     TextData[{
      CounterBox["MySection"], ".", 
      CounterBox["MySubsection"], " -"}], CellBaseline -> Baseline], 
    Inherited}, {Inherited, Inherited}},
 CounterIncrements->"MySubsection",
 FontSize->16
]
```

---

Here's the end result, for a simple notebook:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you rcollyer. I would have kept making "new" groupings if it wasn't for you pointing it out. Never again. Then again, I shouldn't say never.

Comment: @jmlopez I still have to work out what the others do; I think `"InputGrouping"` and `"OutputGrouping"` are obvious, but `"GroupTogetherGrouping"` and `"GroupTogetherNestedGrouping"`? Not a clue there.

Comment: I think that `GroupTogetherGrouping` is used when you want to do manual grouping. For instance, if you create two input cells in a new notebook and then you go to `Cell > Grouping > Group Cells/Group Together` then you'll see that grouping. Just look at the expression of each cell by going to `Cell > Show Expression`. You will see that one there. I'm not sure how to make the other one show up though. Could be when you have a two title cells maybe? since you have nested groups inside a title cell.

Comment: @jmlopez and @rcollyer, you probably figured it out in the intervening four years but `GroupTogetherNestedGrouping` is just how `"Item*"` cells group together, that is, anything tagged with `GroupTogetherNestedGrouping` will either group in the same group as a previous cell with `GroupTogetherNestedGrouping` set and the same second value, as a subgroup if the second value is larger than that of the previous, and no grouping if it's larger. It seems `GroupTogetherGrouping` will only group with cells with the same second value (or none), hence the lack of `"Nested"`.

Comment: TextData only allows one argument

Comment: the code doesn't reflect the screenshot either

Comment: @Rainb as a point of note, this is 8 years old. But, the fix was simple: use a `List` to contain all the arguments of the `TextData`. Once that's done, they can be used to create the screenshot.