# Do ShowGroupOpener and TitleGrouping suffice to control cell grouping?

Tags: cells

[ Running Mathematica 9.0.1.0 under Ms Win XP Ver 5.1.2600 ]

Here I group toghter ;-) some relate questions about cell grouping, because I presume that they all pertain to the same cell options (or strictly siblings), but I can't figure out what they are.

I have just read [SubTitle and SubSubTitle do not group by default](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/subtitle-and-subsubtitle-do-not-group-by-default) and [Making cells group](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6015/making-cells-group) but, may be, I misunderstood something.

Premise:

1. I have set (`Edit > Preferences > Show open/close icon for cell groups`) 'On'
2. I have set (`Format > Edit stylesheet I have set ShowGroupOpener`) 'True' for `title` / `subtitle` / `subsubtitle` / `section` /`subsection` / `subsusbsection` in the stylesheet we are talking about.

Now:

1a.
`Subtitle` cell still don't show the group opener

1b.
`Subtitle` cell still don't act as group operner/closer (I mean the opposite of `Title` or `Section` behaviour)

2.
`Subsubtitle` cell show the group opener only after the first one. Example

- `title`
- `subtitle`
- `subsubtitle` (no)
- `subsubtitle` (yes)
- `subsubtitle` (yes)

3.
I have created a new style `undertitle` and set it options `ShowGroupOpener` but

3a
`GroupOpener` is still missing

3b
The same occur as described in 1b.

3c.
After setting:

1. `AllowGroupCLose` True
2. `CellGroupingRule` `{"TitleGrouping", 25}` (I did because it is `{"TitleGrouping", 20}` for `Subsubtitle` and `{"TitleGrouping", 30}` for `Section`)
3. `AllowReverseGroupCLose` 'True'

3d
Still the same occur as described in 1b.

Can you, please, point out the underlying problems and dispel a bit of the havoc I made ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Just to make sure, what are your problems are. Did you have any content under the cells you want to have a GroupOpener. The point is that if you have no content in the cells belonging to the group, the GroupOpener does not show up.

Comment: its difficult to tell what goes wrong without seeing the full notebooks, but the group openers are only shown when there is something to open, that is at least one cell that belongs to the group which the cell would open/close. So I think the openers should appear as soon as you insert e.g. an empty text cell below those cells which don't show an opener...

Comment: The GroupOpener doesn't appear despite of the text cells below the Subsubtitle. I have just now noticed that it appears if a cell is inserted  above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have the same problem. The open and close button for the 1st subtitle, subsection... anyway the 1st of everything disappeared. Long time ago, it didn't look like this.
[image: pictures below show that the 1st disappear, while all others after the 1st appear]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember, if you ask a question, to accept the answer, if appropriate, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to the question, but rather a comment.