# PageBreakAbove -> True breaks CellMargins

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options, pagelayout

Top `CellMargin` of the cell with `PageBreakAbove` is ignored in SlideShow environment (or for `ShowPageBreaks -> True`).

```
CreateDocument[
    { Cell["s1", "Section"
        , Background -> LightBlue
        , CellMargins -> 100 {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}
      ]
    , Cell["s2", "Section"
        , Background -> LightBlue
        , CellMargins -> 100 {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}
        , PageBreakAbove -> True
      ]
    }
  , ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "SlideShow"
]
```

[image]

If `"CellBreak"` cell is put manually it works:

```
CreateDocument[ 
    { Cell["s1",...], Cell["", "PageBreak"], Cell["s2", ...] }
  , ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "SlideShow"
]
```

But I need automatic page breaking.

Is there any fix? Is this a bug?

In addition to Slideshow environment it also breaks .pdf printout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### tl;dr; fix:

```
CreateDocument[
    { Cell["s1", "Section", CellMargins -> 100 {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}]
    , Cell["s2", "Section"
        , CellMargins -> 100 {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}
        , PageBreakAbove -> True
        , CellElementSpacings -> {"ClosedGroupTopMargin" -> 100}
      ]
    }
  , ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "SlideShow"
]
```

#### WRI Support response

> "It's using the `"ClosedGroupTopMargin"` instead.  This is preferentially used whenever the p**revious cell ends a closed cell group or the previous cell has the `CellGroupingRules` set to use `"SectionGrouping"`**.  The behavior is not documented, but it's **most definitely not a bug.**"
>
> `"ClosedGroupTopMargin"` is a non-documented sub-option of the `CellElementSpacings` notebook option. As mentioned above, its behavior is not documented, but the option itself is preferred whenever the previous cell has the `CellGroupingRules` set to `"SectionGrouping"`. Because of this, the workaround to set `CellGroupingRules` to `Automatic` works.
>
> - CASE:3934040

#### Additional insight

So using `CellElementSpacings -> {"ClosedGroupTopMargin" -> 50}` does what I need.

Worth to mention that `"ClosedGroupTopMargin"` greater than parent top `CellMargins` will be clipped to the latter so `100` will still be `50` if `CellMargins` is e.g. `{{0, 0}, {0, 50}}`

Answer (score 3):

### Update: How to fix the bug

I've found where the bug lives: it is the option `CellGroupingRules -> {"SectionGrouping", 30}` of the built-in `"Section"` style. Overriding this option with anything like `CellGroupingRules -> Automatic` recovers the lost upper cell margin:

```
CreateDocument[
    { Cell["s1", "Section"
        , Background -> LightBlue
        , CellMargins -> 100 {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}
      ]
    , Cell["s2", "Section"
        , Background -> LightBlue
        , CellMargins -> 100 {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}
        , PageBreakAbove -> True
        , CellGroupingRules -> Automatic
      ]
    }
  , ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "SlideShow"
]
```

I think that this fix proves that the behavior described in the question is a bug. Please report it to the support.

---

### Original answer

> Is this a bug?

Probably only the developer can give definitive answer, but there are high chances that this behavior is "by design" since (emphasis is mine):

> `CellMargins` is an option for `Cell` that specifies the absolute margins in printer's points to leave **around a cell**.
>
> `PageBreakAbove` is an option for `Cell` which specifies whether a page break should be made **immediately above the cell** if the notebook that contains the cell is printed.

From the above it is natural to expect that the page break *immediately above* the cell shouldn't be above the upper cell margin (which itself is *immediately above* the cell). So probably it isn't a bug (but still worth to ask the support).

What indeed looks like a bug is that if we add `PageBreakBelow -> True` for the first cell (and remove `PageBreakAbove -> True` from the second), we get exactly the same: the upper margin of the *second* cell is lost, but the bottom margin of the first cell is kept! So I recommend to file a bug report for `PageBreakBelow`.

As a workaround one can use `CellFrameMargins` (with appropriate setting for `CellFrame` which should be turned on for the corresponding side of the cell) instead if  `CellMargins` because `CellFrameMargins` doesn't exhibit the described behavior in conjunction with `PageBreakAbove`. A drawback is that it changes the background filling (everything inside of the `CellFrame` is filled by the `Background` option).

Comment: Thanks again for your insights. Here's a better representation of my real case: `CreateDocument[{Cell["Section", "Section"], 
  Cell["s2", "Test", PageBreakAbove -> True], Cell["s1", "Test"]}, 
 ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "SlideShow",  StyleDefinitions -> 
  Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],     Cell[StyleData["Test"]     , CellGroupingRules -> {"GroupTogetherGrouping", 0}     , Background -> LightBlue
 , CounterIncrements -> "Test"              
 , CellMargins -> {{50, 50}, {50, 150}}  ]}]]` So unfortunately setting `CellGropuingRules` for `Test` cells would...

Comment: ...would break my plan but your fix works even when I set it for the Section above the cell break, which allows me to presereve Test's GroupTogetherGrouping. So many thanks and indeed there appears to be a problem with section grouping.

Comment: Received the response, see my answer. Had to drop the bug tag.