# Unexpected behaviors in built-in functions

Tags: functions, programming, guidelines

*Existence of this topic is discussed in [this mathematica.meta post](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2247/5478)*.

---

I'm sure I am not the only non-beginner in WL who from time to time finds themselves not being able to predict an outcome of a specific function or being surprised it returned something. E.g.:

```
FileExistsQ[""] (*unevaluated + message*)
```

I'm talking about cases which have in common that such problematic outcomes could be considered an exception from a convention/best practices, or even an apparent bug. Sometimes they are just that, and sometimes there is a deeper explanation, deep enough not to be obvious when a problem occurs.

Anyway, the time is wasted on debugging or guessing which exceptions to handle.

A cheat-sheet with those cases can facilitate better programming.

Points to be fulfilled by an on-topic answer:

- *observed* behavior deviates from the *expected* behavior

  based on either documentation or a pattern established by other functions, **please provide links or explanation**.
- documented/officially supported features
- features that in principle work correctly/as designed

What is NOT on topic:

- bug reports

  (we should consider allowing exposing bugs reported *n* versions earlier and still affecting poor programmers)
- backward incompatible changes

  there is a separate thread for this: [Incompatible Changes since Mathematica Version 7?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56728/5478)
- very localized/subjective report

  (need to think how to define them well as the line is blurred here)

An example is worth 1000 words so I will start with the case of `...Q` functions. The whole thread is meant to be community wiki so feel free to suggest/make edits.

---

Index:

- [`***Q` functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/159896/5478)
- [Functions supporting for `Directory[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160085/5478)
- [Exceptions in the standard stylesheet/style inheritance stack](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160539/5478)
- [Arguments conventions for export like functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169598/5478)
- [Exceptions to "the first option's value wins" rule](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184867/5478) (*the most recent update*)

---

Related links:

- [tutorial/SomeGeneralNotationsAndConventions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeGeneralNotationsAndConventions.html)

Comment: Candidates for inclusion? [(1699)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1699/121), [(108231)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108231/121), [(119223)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119223/121),

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am not sure, I feel like they are closer to common piftalls than to bugs/broken conventions that I aim here. But I need to think about it. At the end everyone is free to post here so I will certainly not mind it.

Comment: I'm not sure either, I put them to your attention and trust your judgement.  I'll link anything else that comes to mind, with the same intent.

Answer (score 18):

### `...Q` functions that can return something else than `True` or `False`

#### TL;DR;

Those exceptions return *unevaluated* or `$Failed` which needs handling.

Or if you don't want to think about that and only `True` is what matters then use `TrueQ[]` along with these predicate functions, e.g. `TrueQ[FileExistsQ[filename]]`.

It may not be a complete list yet, but here's a start:

- `FileExistsQ`
- `DirectoryQ`
- `GeoWithinQ`
- `ImageInstanceQ`
- `SocketReadyQ`

Following two just coincidentally have `Q` at the end but let's include it here even if they are clear as exceptions.

- `EllipticNomeQ`
- `InverseEllipticNomeQ`

#### Further reading:

One can be beaten by:

```
FileExistsQ[""]
```

> FileExistsQ::fstr: File specification is not a string of one or more characters.
>
> ```
> FileExistsQ[""]
> ```

Why it can be surprising:

> An important feature of all the Wolfram Language property-testing functions whose names end in Q is that they always return `False` if they cannot determine whether the expression you give has a particular property.
>
> - [tutorial/PuttingConstraintsOnPatterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PuttingConstraintsOnPatterns.html#9762)

How to find them? One way is to investigate messages (except usage):

```
Select[
  {#, Column@
      DeleteCases[Messages@Evaluate@ToExpression[#], 
       HoldPattern[
         Verbatim[HoldPattern][MessageName[_, "usage"]]] :> _]} & /@ 
   Names["*Q"]
  , #[[2]] =!= Column[{}] &
  ] // Grid[#, Alignment -> {Left, Top}] &
```

It maybe makes sense to return `$Failed` in case of connection problems, but I'd say it is better not to name your function with `...Q` if it needs e.g. internet connection.

[image: messages associated with *Q functions]

Comment: A corollary of this is that for safety, one might want to use `TrueQ[]` along with these predicate functions, e.g. `TrueQ[FileExistsQ[filename]]`.

Comment: To me, this clearly looks like a consequence of the absence of exception-handling practices in idiomatic Mathematica (meaning, as recommended by the docs). The `Q` - predicates should return `True` or `False`, but when the input is invalid, it would make much more sense to throw an exception (which would be a much clearer semantics),than to remain unevaluated (which expressly breaks the `Q` contract) and issue a message. But for that, it should be possible to document that functions can throw exceptions, and that would require a better-integrated into the language exception-handling mechanism.

Comment: Another thing I forgot to mention: recall that `If[]` has a four argument form, where the first three arguments are the usual ones and the fourth one is the statement to evaluate if the predicate does not return `True` or `False`. This is one more possibility for the exception handling indicated by Kuba in the answer above.

Comment: `EllipticNomeQ` never returns `True` or `False`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 interesting exceptions :)

Comment: `FileExistsQ[""]` has been fixed (<= V12.3.1).  Maybe `DirectoryQ`, too. Can anyone confirm? -- Almost every `*Q[]` fails to return `True` or `False` if they have the wrong number of arguments, so one might want to exclude the `"argx"` messages as well as the `"usage"` ones. (They're loaded only after you make a mistake.)

Answer (score 8):

### Support for `Directory[]`

This was always puzzling me but I'm happy to delete this answer if I'm alone in this.

#### TL;DR;

Functions that do NOT respect `Directory[]`:

- `NotebookOpen    (*1*)`
- `NotebookLocate  (*1*)`
- `NotebookSave    (*2*)`
- `SystemDialogInput`

1. Respects `CurrentValue[NotebookPath]` 
   quick fix is to e.g. `NotebookOpen @ AbsoluteFileName @ _`
2. Respects the most recent notebook saving directory! You need to `FileNameJoin` + `Directory[]`

Functions that DO but one might not expect that knowing cases above:

- `NotebookImport (*!*)`
- `CDFDeploy`

#### Motivation

I came to this neighbourhood as of Mathematica V7 and I didn't have much experience with command line etc. In this context the border between the Kernel and the FrontEnd was very blurred at the beginning.

It took me quite a while to get used to that and even though I can explain it now, I am still claiming it is confusing.

The more that `ref / NotebookPath`:

> This function has not been fully integrated into the long-term Wolfram Language, and is subject to change.

Answer (score 6):

## Exceptions in the standard stylesheet/style inheritance stack

### Quick list of deviations

*Feel free to add anything, try to make it short and if needed add examples or more explanation at the end of the answer.*

- `"DockedCell"` style is inserted in every `DockedCell` **before** any explicit style.

  So either you overwrite "DockedCells" in your stylesheet or use explicit options in `Cell`, see `"DockedCell"` example.

- `"InlineCell"` same story but less problematic as "InlineCell" styles are less invasive. So keep that in mind when defining custom `DefaultInlineCellStyle`.

- `"InlineCellEditing"` as above if you want to adjust/switch of orange-ish background that appears during edition you need to modify this style even even for custom `DefaultInlineCellStyle`

- `All` style + `FormatType` issue, see topic linked below for full explanation. TL;DR;? better do not use `All`.

Points from above, with a little background, are mentioned in [Order/Dependency of Styles in a Stylesheet](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14835/5478).

- `Button(Box)'s` `Appearance` is inserted explicitly during typesetting

  which makes it impossible to set `Button's` appearance via a stylesheet or style with outer `ButtonBoxOptions`. You need to set `Appearance -> Inherited` to do so. See `Button Appearance` example.

- cell's top `CellMargin` behavior in presence of `PageBreakAbove -> True` in that cell.

  See: [154542](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/154542/5478). Quick fix is to add `CellElementSpacings -> {"ClosedGroupTopMargin" -> 100}` option.

- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug): notebook's `WindowSize->All` ignores the very bottom `CellMargins`

  see more in [112593](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/112593/5478)

- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) `DockedCell` on Windows can't be `White` [160356](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160356/5478)

### Motivation

The idea and scheme is quite simple see: [**tutorial / WorkingWithStylesheets / Inheritance**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStylesheets.html)

But there is no way to check where current setting for e.g. `FontSize` comes from. Which makes 'debugging' styles extremely painful. Any exception from the simple scheme makes it even worse, that is why one needs to know what to expect.

### Examples

- `"DockedCell"`

```
CreateDocument[{},
 DockedCells -> Cell["test", "myDockedCell"],
 StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
    Cell[StyleData["myDockedCell"], Background -> Red, FontSize -> 30]
    }]
 ]
```

The docked cell is gray despite stylesheet `Background` spec for `myDockedCell`, `FontSize` works well. That is because `"DockedCell"` style has `Background` option.

So every `Cell[content, style, opts]` inside `DockedCells` effectively becomes `Cell[content, "DockedCell, style, opts]`...

- `Button Appearance`

```
Style[
 Button["LabeL", Print[1]],
 ButtonBoxOptions -> {ImageSize -> {200, 200}, Appearance -> "FramedPalette"}
]
```

`ImageSize` is respected but `Appearance` not, you need `Button["LabeL", Print[1], Appearance -> Inherited]` to make it work but then you ask yourself, why bother with nice setup and not create `myButton` function and put all stuff there?

Official classification of the issue: [116030#comment315233_116030](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115888/evaluation-leak-from-dynamic-in-buttons-action/116030#comment315233_116030)

Comment: That `Button` one I never knew about. That's got the potential to cause some nasty confusion.

Answer (score 6):

## Arguments conventions for export like functions

It is not that tough yet I'm always confused, so again, if that is only me let me know and I will delete that answer.

```
Export[      "where", what, how]
CDFDeploy[   "where", what]
Write[       "where", what..]
WriteString[ "where", what..]
LinkWrite[   "where", what]
Save[        "where", what]
DumpSave[    "where", what]

Put[         what.., "where"]
PutAppend[   what.., "where"]    
CloudDeploy[ what, "where"]
CloudPut[    what, "where"]
CloudSave[   what, "where"]
CloudExport[ what, how, "where"]
```

So `Put/PutAppend` order and shuffled `CloudExport` are outliers one has to keep in mind.

Comment: So to memorize: "*Where* is my PC? At the *end* (of the question)." The exceptional "C" is a legacy one. :) -- And, yes, it is confusing so do not delete the answer please.

Answer (score 5):

## Exceptions to "first option's value takes precedence" rule

One usually expects `expr[opt1 -> a, opt1 -> b]` to be equivalent to `expr[opt1 -> a]`. At the end this is how `Replace*` functions work: `opt1 /. {opt1 -> a, opt1 ->b }` returns `a`.

Thare are exceptions where the last one is chosen though, mostly related to a FrontEnd.

Many of them are related to controllers because of how they are implemented. They don't use `OptionValue` to extract options but something along those lines:

```
controller[_Dynamic, ___, specificOption -> specificValue, ___]:=...
```

See `SaveDefinitions` example, you can always lookup definitions with `PrintDefinitions`.

1. `StyleDefinitions` option for notebooks
2. `SaveDefinitions -> False` for `DynamicModule`

(* in construction *)

Code samples:

Ad 1.

```
CreateDocument[Pane["Test", 600],     
 StyleDefinitions -> "Dialog.nb", StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb",     
 WindowTitle      -> "A dialog" , WindowTitle      -> "A notebook"
]

 (* Default.nb with "A dialog" title" *)
```

Ad 2.

```
 foo[]:=1;
 ToBoxes @ DynamicModule[{x}, Dynamic@foo[], SaveDefinitions -> False, SaveDefinitions -> True]

(* foo included! *)
```