# What is wrong with White Background for a DockedCell?

Tags: bugs, notebooks, options, cells

**Bug introduced in V10.4 or earlier and persists through V11.3**

---

```
SetOptions[
  EvaluationNotebook[]
, DockedCells -> Flatten @ {
    Cell[
      BoxData @ ToBoxes[Framed[InputForm@#, Background -> White]]
    , CellFrameMargins -> 15
    , CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
    , Background -> #
    ] & /@ {
      Inherited, Red, GrayLevel[1.], None, GrayLevel[.99], Blue
    }}
]
```

Apparently you can not have `White` `Background` for a `DockedCells`.

And if you do not obey they will take your margins, too!

[image]

Any reasonable explanation?

Notice the `None` case is documented:

> If `Background->None` is set, then the margins are only applied if a `CellFrame` is present. If the cell frame is not drawn on all sides, then the margin will only be applied to the sides with a frame setting.

V11.2 Win7

> [CASE:3975061] was created

Comment: Not the same for me (OSX, mma 11.2.0) : background is white for `GrayLevel[1.]` and `None`. Why `Inherited` gives gray ?

Comment: @SquareOne `Inherited` inherits from `"DockedCell"` style even if it is not present explicitly in a docked cell, not really documented :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [...] It does appear as though DockedCells cannot have `White` as their `Background` specification. I have filed a report with our developers regarding this incorrect limitation so that they may investigate and look to address the issue in a future release. [...]
>
> - WRI Support

The workaround is to use 'almost' white:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[]
, DockedCells -> Cell[
    BoxData @ ToBoxes[Framed[InputForm@GrayLevel[.999]]]
  , CellFrameMargins -> 15
  , CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
  , Background -> GrayLevel[.999]
  ]
]
```