# Create new cell that is not part of any group of cells (not grouped)

Tags: notebooks, cells

I'd like to create a new cell that is not grouped with the previous cell

The documentation on creating a new cell says this:

To Create a New Cell:
Move the pointer in the notebook window until it becomes a horizontal I-beam. Click, and a cell insertion bar will appear; start typing. By default, new cells are the Wolfram System input cells.

However, this creates a cell that is grouped with the previous one. How do I create an entirely new one separate from the previous.

Pictures below to better illustrate what I mean:

What I don't want is this:

[image]

becomes this when I press the enter key:

[image]

I would rather have an entirely new "un-grouped" cell.

Comment: FYI, Merged cells are a single cell so it is not the best term here. The second cell is a separate one here. You can adjust `CellGroupingRules` based on this [118649](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118649/5478) to make it outside the previous cell group but it may be a pain to maintain this. What is your final goal. What do you want to group with what and why is grouping a problem? p.s. you can also set `CellGrouping -> Manual` for the notebook and do not have any grouping by default.

Comment: @Kuba I want to separate out other code that follows the previous ones so that I can conveniently click on the outermost cell of previous codes to run them without running anything else after that. Is there a more convenient way?

Comment: You can group 'parts' by adding a Section cell (Alt+4) or any similar in front of each 'part'. Then you can click on the common cell bracket and hit Shift+Return.